# Remove everything after certain string in Excel 2010

Tags: excel

I have this string:

```
Category1 > SubCategory11 > SubSubCategory111 > Something

Category2 > SubCategory21 > SomethingElse

Category3 > SubCategory31 > SubSubCategory32 > SubSubSubCategory33 > AnotherSomethingElse

Category4 > Else
```

How can I remove everything that is after the last ">" ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A formula approach:

```
=LEFT(A1, FIND("|", SUBSTITUTE(A1, ">", "|", LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1, ">", "")))))
```

TO get rid of the > too:

```
=TRIM(LEFT(A1, FIND("|", SUBSTITUTE(A1, ">", "|", LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1, ">", ""))))-1))
```

Comment: Thanks, but have no idea where to put that code :) Any help...? I mean, I have the data in A1, and I put the code in B1, but it gives me an error...

Comment: That's exactly how I used the formula.  Here's a link to my site where I posted a sample file called "RemoveString.xls"           https://sites.google.com/a/madrocketscientist.com/jerrybeaucaires-excelassistant/

Comment: Ok, got it now, I changed all the "," in the above code, into ";" and now it works :) I noticed the difference from this code with the code from the file you've made ;) Just out of curiosity, why's here with "," and in your sample file with ";" ? :)

Comment: And another thing, how to loose the last ">" as well? :) Sorry, forgot to add that :) Can you edit the code, please? Thanks.

Comment: Excel is smart, in the USA Excel uses commas as delimiters, your Excel uses semicolons.  When I saved it Excel used commas, when you opened it Excel "fixed it".

Comment: Ah, ok, got it :) Thanks for the explaination buddy, really appreciate it. If you can edit the code to lose the ">" together with the string which is after it, it would be nice :) Other than that, thanks a lot.

Comment: I edited the original post above to add that new option. Try it out.

Comment: Yeap, it's working as it should, thank you very much for everything buddy. Take care.